# H_SPI conflict when using Wifi on esp32

Tags: esp32

i have a custom PCB that uses ESP32-wroom32U as an MCU , the H_SPI is used with 3 max6675 and K type thermocouples. When i try to read the sensors while using wifi i don't get a reading knowing that when i read the sensors without the wifi it works well. is there any solution ?

```
int MISO2 = 12;
int thermoCS4 = 16;
int thermoCS5 = 15;
int thermoCS6 = 25;
int thermoCLK2 = 14;

MAX6675 thermocouple4(thermoCLK2, thermoCS4, MISO2);
MAX6675 thermocouple5(thermoCLK2, thermoCS5, MISO2);
MAX6675 thermocouple6(thermoCLK2, thermoCS6, MISO2);
```